# Using Silverlight Navigator ... Question

Tags: silverlight

I define 2 pages ( define as navigation:Page )
I put those two pages on the main windows ( the main windows is UserControl )

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    <navigation:Frame 
        Source="/Views/Page1.xaml" 
        x:Name="Page1">
    </navigation:Frame>

    <navigation:Frame 
        Source="/Views/Page2.xaml" 
        x:Name="Page2">                
    </navigation:Frame>

</Grid>
```

Now, When i load the silverlight application - i see the page1 is up. 
But .. how can i switch to page2 ? and back to page1 ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, on your example, Page2 will be displayed over Page1 since its on a grid.

Secondly, the navigation frame should not really be used like that.  The navigation frame is matching the browser URL and that way you can navigate with the browser back button with silverlight.

If you have 2 Navigation Frame in your app, then this is messed up.

I think you should only have 1 navigation frame to switch from Page1 and Page2.

Comment: Actually the navigation frame can be used like that as my example shows.  You can have as many frames in your app as you like.  The main frame can handle the browser journal an any sub frames can Set journalownerhip to ownsjournal.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't see page 2 because page 1 is taking up all of the grid row.  Stick each frame in it's own row.  Here is an example of two frames on 1 page. https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/navdemo/src

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="MainView" />
            <Button Content="Load Area1 with Sub3View"
                    Command="{Binding Path=Load1Command}" />
            <Button Content="Load Area1 with Sub1View"
                    Command="{Binding Path=Load2Command}" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DataToPass, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height=".5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Area1" />
            <nav:Frame Grid.Row="1"
                       Source="{Binding Path=FrameSource}" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height=".5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Area2" />
            <nav:Frame Grid.Row="1"
                       JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"
                       Source="{Binding Path=FrameSource2}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```